# Is it "restaurant DE fruits de mer" or DES? Why?

Tags: articles, de

Is it:

- Je veux aller au restaurant DE fruits de mer.
- Je veux aller au restaurant DES fruits de mer.

What is the rule?

What if the word following the second "de" was also in plural? For instance, "champs."

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

"De" is the right word.

[image]

There are plenty of examples on this [Google page](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22restaurant%20de%20fruits%20de%20mer%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr).

*Rule*

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/de)) **I.− De prend une valeur sémantique en corrélation avec celle du mot subséquent.**
> **C.− De marque une circonstance qui précise (et parfois conditionne) une modalité d'existence ou d'action.**
> **5. La modalité est une appartenance**.
> **b) Qualité, détermination, qualification, caractérisation**.
> − **Spécialement**
> **α) Condition, profession**.
> • Homme de lettres, employée de maison, marchand de vins, agent de change, entrepreneur de/en..., dessinateur de/en..., spécialiste de/en...
> • La mère est dehors toute la journée.  Elle est porteuse de pain de son métier (A. Daudet, Jack,t. 2, 1876, p. 211).
> • À huit heures moins le quart, le secrétaire de mairie de cette dernière localité [Trémentines] nous mettait poliment à la porte (H. Bazin, Vipère,1948, p. 148).
> ♦ **En partic., spécification de la condition, genre**.
> • Un ancien condamné de droit commun (Morand, Londres,1933, p. 107).

"Fruits de champs" is not a likely combination, although it can occur if there is a complement to "champs". Apparently, restaurants where you eat only fruit do not exist, but if a similar  combination became needed for this new type of restaurant it would have to be "restaurant de fruits des champs".

[image]

[Page of examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22fruits%20de%20champs%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr)

Answer (score 1):

***Restaurant des fruits de mer*** would be either a restaurant where oysters, lobsters, shrimps, clams and the likes have their meal served or a restaurant where food is cooked / served by there creatures.

No surprise none is found by search engines.

Comment: Interesting, so the de/des distinction here is a question of whether the article indicates possession?

Comment: Yes, that's a way to understand it. A similar expression where *de* is used and not *des* is *une paire **de** chaussures*.